# How To Access Body/Exchange In Camel Route

Tags: xml, apache-camel, dsl

i am trying to log the exchange or body in a camel route as:

```
<log message="body:${body}"/>
```

This prints blank ie. "body :  ". However some processors are called in the same route by passing parameters as:

```
<bean id="userBean" method="findSomeUser(${body.getUserId})"/>
```

how to log exchange/body from a camel route if one wants to see contents of exchange ?

Comment: See this FAQ if your message body is empty

- http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `Java DSL`, this is how you can print the body of your message;

```
from("file://xml/inbox")
    .log("${body}");
```

If you also want to edit your body or play with it, you can use a `Camel Processor` implementation within the `process()` method as below, so that you can get the body or update the body via the **Exchange** object;

```
from("file://xml/inbox")
    .log("${body}")
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            String myBody = exchange.getIn().getBody();

            System.out.println("This is my body: " + myBody);
        }
    })
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Processed");
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression you used is correct but your body is empty at that time. Try removing setBody part from this route and you will get the same result.

```
 <route >
    <from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=5000"/>
    <setBody>
          <constant>MESSAGE</constant>
     </setBody>
    <log message="body:${body}"/>
 </route>
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression ${body} in the log message is correct , your body might be empty hence it got printed like that. Try setting the body to some value using setBody parameter and try to print the body.